# pytesseract don't work with one digit image

Tags: python, ocr

I have code using pytesseract and work perfect, only don't work when the image I try to recognize are 0 to 9. If image only have one digit don't give any result.

This a sample of image I'm working
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B68PDhV5SW8BdFdWYVRwODBVZk0&usp=sharing

And this the code I'm using

```
    import pytesseract
    varnum= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/img.jpg'))
    varnum = float(varnum)
    print varnum
```

Thanks!!!!

With this code I'm able to read all numbers

```
import pytesseract


start_time = time.clock()
y = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/1.jpg'),config='-psm 10000')
x = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/1.jpg'),config='-psm 10000')

print y
print x

y = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/68.5.jpg'),config='-psm 10000')
x = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/68.5.jpg'),config='-psm 10000')

print y
print x

print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

result

```
>>> 
1
1
68.5
68.5
0.485644155358 seconds
>>>
```

Comment: Can you try like - `varnum= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/img.jpg'),config="-psm 1")` ?

Comment: Or - `varnum= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/img.jpg'),config="-psm 10")` .

Answer (score 10):

You would need to set the Page Segmentation mode to be able to read single character/digits.

From the [tesseract-ocr manual](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) (which is what pytesseract internally uses), you can set the page segmentation mode using -

> **-psm N**
>
> Set Tesseract to only run a subset of layout analysis and assume a
>   certain form of image. The options for N are:
>
> **10 = Treat the image as a single character.**

So you should set the `-psm` option to 10. Example -

```
varnum= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/img.jpg'),config='-psm 10')
```

Comment: For others, noting that the config should two dashes: `config='--psm 10'`