# Reading text from image

Tags: python, image-processing, pytesser

Any suggestions on converting these images to text?  I'm using pytesseract and it's working wonderfully in most cases except this.  Ideally I'd read these numbers exactly.  Worst case I can just try to use PIL to determine if the number to the left of the '/' is a zero.  Start from the left and find the first white pixel, then

[image]
[image]

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

myText = image_to_string(Image.open("tmp/test.jpg"),config='-psm 10')
myText = image_to_string(Image.open("tmp/test.jpg"))
```

The slash in the middle causes issues here.  I've also tried using PIL's '.paste' to add lots of extra black around the image.  There might be a few other PIL tricks I could try, but i'd rather not go that route unless I have to.

I tried using config='-psm 10' but my 8's were coming through as ":" sometimes, and random characters other times.  And my 0's were coming through as nothing.

Reference to: [pytesseract don't work with one digit image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643216/pytesseract-dont-work-with-one-digit-image) for the -psm 10

**_____________EDIT_______________**
Additional samples:

[image]
1BJ2I]

[image]
DIS

[image]
10.I'10

[image]
20.I20

So I'm doing some voodoo conversions that seem to be working for now.  But looks very error prone:

```
def ConvertPPTextToReadableNumbers(text):
    text = RemoveNonASCIICharacters(text)
    text = text.replace("I]", "0")
    text = text.replace("|]", "0")
    text = text.replace("l]", "0")
    text = text.replace("B", "8")
    text = text.replace("D", "0")
    text = text.replace("S", "5")
    text = text.replace(".I'", "/")
    text = text.replace(".I", "/")
    text = text.replace("I'", "/")
    text = text.replace("J", "/")
    return text
```

Ultimately generates:

```
ConvertPPTextToReadableNumbers return text =  18/20
ConvertPPTextToReadableNumbers return text =  0/5
ConvertPPTextToReadableNumbers return text =  10/10
ConvertPPTextToReadableNumbers return text =  20/20
```

Comment: `-psm 10` is for single character recognition, you could try `psm 7` (single text line) Ref: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage

Comment: I left out a few details there, what I did with psm 10 was attempt to crop out the first character and then use psm 10.  I was successfully able to crop out the first character sometimes, but it was inconsistent.  Even when I could crop out an 8 all by itself, it would be interpreted as : or something else so.  And other characters weren't coming through either.  Even when I crop out a 0 all by itself, it come through as a blank.

Comment: Using psm 7, it's consistently reading "0\5" as DIS which honestly might be good enough for my worst case.  I can just check for a D and I'll know that's 0/. If anyone else has a better solution, feel free to chime in.  I wish there was a way to say "Interpret everything as numbers"

Comment: it show some path error, how to resolve it..?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, most OCR tools (like Tesseract) are tuned for working with high-resolution scans of printed text. They do not perform well on low-resolution or pixellated images.

Two possible approaches here are:

1. If the font, background, and layout of your images are completely predictable, you don't need Tesseract at all; it's just complicating matters. Build a library of images representing each character you need to recognize, and [check whether parts of the image are equal to the reference image](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-comparing-images.htm).
2. If that isn't an option, or if it seems too hard, you could upscale the pixellated image using one of [the hq*x algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hqx). The added detail may be sufficient to get Tesseract to reliably recognize the characters.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The font and size is consistent, the spacing changes a bit.  I'll consider trying to upscale if my current implementation becomes a problem.  My only concern with upscale would be that it might take a long time to process.  I prefer something faster since my script is a real-time thing

Answer (score 5):

If anyone still stumbles over this... The problem is that the letters are white and the background is black...in my application, I got an about 98% accuracy after switching that (white background black letters) I just used cv2 for that

Comment: Haha, years later this worked! Glad I checked back here