# Unicode Decode Error while reading text from image

Tags: python, anaconda

I have used this code to read text from an image file.
[Reading text from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218106/reading-text-from-image)

The code is as follows

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

image = Image.open("image.jpg",'r')

myText = image_to_string(Image.open(open('maxresdefault.jpg')),config='-psm 10')
myText = image_to_string(Image.open(open('maxresdefault.jpg')))
print(myText)
```

> Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 278: character maps to

Tried to solve this error from following:[UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Then got error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004993/5774004

Comment: At what point are you getting this error?  On the Image.open()?  the image_to_string() ??

Answer (score 1):

As per `Image` documentation (`help(Image.open)`), the image files must be opened in the binary mode:

```
open('maxresdefault.jpg', 'rb')
```

Comment: I am getting this error: ValueError: bad mode 'rb'. Just found that **Image** doesn't support 'rb' mode

Comment: The 'rb' flag must be passed to open(), not Image.open().

Answer (score 0):

Load the Image in binary format.

Changing the following code solved the problem for me.

```
import PIL.Image
pil_image = PIL.Image.open(image_path, "rb")
```

Hope it helps !